# SigepWeb NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, web-service

Consegui fazer a geração do codigo e o digito verificador da etiqueta, porém a correios pede um padrão unico para impressão e não sei direito se a sigep-web ja fornece isso em sua API ou não.

https://github.com/stavarengo/php-sigep

existe o link acima que é um biblioteca onde consigo realizar a impressão da etiqueta de acordo com as exigências da correios, porém está em PHP, alguém conhece algo do tipo voltado para NodeJS? preciso estar gerando o PDF para impressão da etiqueta e acredito que montar esse layout não é o melhor caminho.

aceito sugestões construtivas claro, por que se não encontrar nada voltado para nodejs terei que desenvolver.